# Error: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Tags: java, android, button, html, oncreate

I got a problem with my android app. I got a button and and event associated , but when I click the first time an error appears

> "spans cannot have zero lenght".

. But when I click the second time, the event onclick runs well..
look at my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    final Button selectAltitude = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAltitude1);
    final Button selectAltitude2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAltitude2); 
    
    selectAltitude2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view){
            
                String tempAlt = selectAltitude2.getText().toString();
                selectAltitude2.setText(selectAltitude.getText().toString());
                selectAltitude.setText(tempAlt);
        }
    });
    }
```

The xml code with the two buttons (a deprecated warning occurs):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AbsoluteLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/black"> 

<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAltitude1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:layout_x="257dp"
        android:layout_y="419dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable1"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:minHeight="10dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="@string/button_meters"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
        
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAltitude2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
            android:layout_x="295dp"
            android:layout_y="419dp"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:minWidth="64dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="@string/button_feet"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

When I click the first time Log cat interacts with:

> 04-06 20:01:39.865: I/Sensors(6946): sendDelay --- 200000000 04-06
>
> 20:01:39.865: D/SensorManager(6946): JNI - sendDelay 04-06
>
> 20:01:39.865: I/SensorManager(6946): Set normal delay = true 04-06
>
> 20:01:39.890: E/SpannableStringBuilder(6946): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
>
> spans cannot have a zero length 04-06 20:01:39.890:
>
> E/SpannableStringBuilder(6946): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot
>
> have a zero length

can you help ne?;)

Comment: Add activity_main.xml code too.

Comment: Please post a stack trace from Logcat

Comment: It's updated now :) thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have run into the same error entries in LogCat. In my case it's caused by the 3rd party keyboard I am using. When I change it back to Android keyboard, the error entry does not show up any more.

This is the most probable cause of this issue as there is also a bug report for SwiftKey:

http://support.swiftkey.net/forums/116693-2-bug-reports/suggestions/2994580-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-

Comment: @Carlos Piedade Read this answer and links which I posted here.

Comment: i'm sorry for the waiting.. I saw your answer, and I can't understand how can I fiz my problem. Did you see the update I made in my post and the LogCat info? thanks

Comment: @CarlosPiedade I saw your updated post. It might i shared the link solve your problem. Read my post carefully.

Comment: can you explain me how I can I change to the Android keyboard?I can't understand how can I do that change..

Comment: @CarlosPiedade You can try following [this guide](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/03/07/android-1-change-keyboard/). However, your default device keyboard might automatically come with SwiftKey (this was the case with my Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1).

Answer (score 0):

To try to debug this error, first go to your android terminal / console and execute this command:

```
ps | grep THE_ERROR_PID_YOU_GET_(IT_IS_A_NUMBER)
```

then if the output comes out as your app... it is your app causing the error. Try to look for empty `Strings` that you pass into the `layout`.

I had this exact same problem and it was my fault as I was passing an empty `String` into my layout. After changing the `""` to `" "` this error went away.

If you don't get your app from the console output, then it is something else causing it (probably, as others said, the android keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late. In case someone still needs help with having to **click the second time for the the event onclick to run**, I removed this:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

The onClick event will now work on the first click.