# . "10-29 11:04:53.626: E/SpannableStringBuilder(2815): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length"

Tags: android, eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova

Am developing android app using phonegap,jquery mobile,eclipse .

this my error (which appears when you clear the name or password to zero characters and leave the field ):

```
10-29 11:04:53.626: E/SpannableStringBuilder(2815):
SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been sufficiently answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839327/2500355)

Maybe you're using a 3'rd party keyboard. Try to change back to the Android keyboard.
How? [This](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/03/07/android-1-change-keyboard/) link should be helpfull.